# Will I be able to push notifications from WP8 to a Windows Store app?

Tags: ssl, azure, windows-8, microsoft-metro, push-notification

I need to pass messages between a WP8 app and a Windows Store app. It's sort of a "peer-to-peer" situation in that they will both send and respond to messages from each other, but it's also sort of a "client/server" situation in that the Windows Store app will have 1..N WP8 apps that it is conversing with.

After being beaten about the head and shoulders for my first ideas of trying to use either email or SkyDrive rather sneakily, I'm now considering these possible architectures:

1) Direct Push Notifications
(a) The WP8 app sends Push Notifications to the Windows Store app via a URI it is provided after this conversation takes place:
Windows Store app: "*Will you send me updates?*" 
WP8 app: "*Yes.*" 
Windows Store app: "*Okay, here's where to send them.*"
(b) Windows 8 responds to the arriving msgs.

2) Push-Pull using the Cloud
(a) WP8 sends data to the cloud (Azure?)
(b) Windows 8 app periodically polls for it

3) SSL (Using components from someone like /NSoftware (IP*Works))

The messages from WP8 are rather frequent (every 15 minutes, on average), but small/short (short enough to be a Tweet, in fact). The Windows 8 app deals with these msgs "behind the scenes." The user is not aware of them until he runs the associated app.

Comment: Option 1 seems the best way - perhaps implement your own API which queues all of your WP8 notifications and manages which users they go to, which then pushes the notification to Microsoft's servers to be distributed to wherever. Azure helps a lot with this - you can authenticate with their Microsoft account, and push notifications are super simple.

Comment: 3) This is definitely possible, you could use IP*Works! SSL toolkit to create a client/server application. It wouldn't be using any push notifications, but one side could be hosting an instance of IPDaemon, while the other has IPPort. Then when you need to push something to the other application, you can send something to tell the other what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There weren't any question marks :) but here's my take:

1. Push notifications would certainly work, but given your "behind the scenes" comment, you may want to look specifically into ["raw notifications"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Raw-notifications-sample-3bc28c5d), which do use the push notification mechanism but aren't associated with UI (like a tile, toast or badge).  Pushed toast notifications, for instance, are dropped if the client if off-line.
2. The frequency of the messages makes me leery of the polling approach given impact on battery life (that said, not sure how a push notification with background task would compare). With the polling approach too you'd need to have some way on your "cloud service" to maintain messages (storage) and then feed back the right messages on each poll, etc.  You'd also need to handle the scaling and availability aspects that WNS would do 'free.'  Not rocket science, but more work.  The push notification is kind of 'fire-and-forget'.
3. With sockets, you might have more control to the extent the sandboxed model exposes functionality you need.  It seems like more moving parts though, and I'd likely go that route only if the other two approaches are otherwise unviable.

Comment: There was a ? in the title; BTW, your article/blog post on the subject is what brought it to my consciousness.

Comment: ah yes, missed that "?" :)  feel free to follow up off-line, I'd be interested in what approach you do take - no 'right' answer here.

Comment: joneil AT Microsoft DOT com (or use the contact me link - my photo - on blog)